# Erro de referências para subir aplicação no Tompcat pelo Eclipse

Tags: java, jsf, eclipse, tomcat

Boa tarde, galera!

É o o seguinte: Estou com um aplicação JSF que, se eu der build dela pelo maven (maven install) e pegar o .war gerado e der deploy nele pelo tomcat, roda normalmente.
Porém não consigo rodar diretamente pelo eclipse, utilizando a mesma instalação do tomcat. Lança o erro de `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`para as dependências.

Uma delas:

```
GRAVE: Error configuring application listener of class [org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1365)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:521)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4607)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5146)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:932)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:475)
```

Nesse caso, a dependência está da seguinte forma no **web.xml:**

```
   <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

e no **pom.xml:**

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId>
   <version>2.4.2.Final</version>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Não estou conseguindo entender o motivo de dar erro dessas dependências ao rodar pelo eclipse, mas no servidor ele compila normalmente.
Se aguém puder lançar uma luz...

Answer (score 2):

Bom, após muita pesquisa, descobri o problema:
Eu precisava incluir as dependências do maven nos assemblies a serem compilados pelo Eclipse, ao inicar o servidor pela IDE.

Para fazer isso:

1. Botão direito no projeto - Preferences.
2. Deployment Assembly. Clicar em Add.
3. Java Build Path Entries. Next.
4. Selecionar Maven Dependencies e aplicar.